# Popoverpresentation viewcontroller and constraint trouble

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, constraints, uipopoverpresentationcontroller

I try to invoke a popoverpresentation viewcontroller in order to share an image on an ipad, but when that happens I get the error 'unable to satisfy constraints'.

The thing is in order to fix this I deleted all constraints so I could start over, but even with no constraints I get the same error.

So my question is. Is this a bug or do I have to set the constraints for the popoverpresentation viewcontroller.

Here is my code:

```
print("Current device is an iPad")
print("Current device is \(UIDevice.current)")

if let imageCheck = image {
    let imageToShare = [imageCheck]
    let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: imageToShare, applicationActivities: nil)

    activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = super.view
    self.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

And the error in the console :

```
Current device is an iPad
Current device is <UIDevice: 0x280c8d260>
2019-12-26 20:31:22.662290+0100 Petfie[2184:756367] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282f83c00 LPLinkView:0x15be4c7a0.leading == UILayoutGuide:0x2835a8c40'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.leading   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282f83840 H:[LPLinkView:0x15be4c7a0]-(59)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIActivityContentTitleView:0x15be47560 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282f85d10 H:|-(0)-[_UIActivityContentTitleView:0x15be47560]   (active, names: '|':_UINavigationBarContentView:0x15be57940 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282f85d60 _UIActivityContentTitleView:0x15be47560.trailing == _UINavigationBarContentView:0x15be57940.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282f9eb20 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' _UINavigationBarContentView:0x15be57940.width == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282f83b10 'UIView-leftMargin-guide-constraint' H:|-(16)-[UILayoutGuide:0x2835a8c40'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'](LTR)   (active, names: '|':_UIActivityContentTitleView:0x15be47560 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282f83c00 LPLinkView:0x15be4c7a0.leading == UILayoutGuide:0x2835a8c40'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.leading   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Answer (score 9):

I just fixed the same problem on my own project.

When showing a UIActivityViewController on iPad, you either need to set the `sourceView` AND `sourceRect` properties, or you need to set the `barButtonItem` property.

On my project, I fixed the issue by adding the following code to the block that runs when the `shareButton` is tapped:

```swift
activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = shareButton.frame
```

The `sourceRect` is the CGRect that the the `UIActivityViewController` "pops out" of. The arrow on the `UIActivityViewController` will point to the `sourceRect`

Comment: I was missing this salient point that the sourceRect is where the UIActivityViewController "pops out" of. Previously, I just made it the parent view's frame, which did not work for me! Thank you!